# Jquery not sending textarea name="post_description"

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

My jQuery code is not sending a value from the textarea `name="post_description"`

```html
<form id="post" method="post">
  <div class="input-group">
    <textarea name="post_description" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['description']; ?>" rows="4" ng-model="description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="share_result"></div>
  <a id="share" class="btn-custom">
    <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $lang['share']; ?>
  </a>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#share").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var postimg = $("#post").serialize();
    $.post("posts/post_image.php", postimg).done(function(data) {
      $("#share_result").html(data);
    }).fail(function() {
      //alert("Error submitting forms!");
    })
  })
})
```

On the backend:

```
$post_description = $_POST['post_description'];
```

It's returning as undefined index but the names do match

Comment: Open dev tools and check the request contains the value from the field. Then you'll know if the issue is JS picking up the value, or in your PHP receiving it

Comment: Also did you try to print on the backend the value of $post_description ?

Comment: Also note that judging by the `ng-model` attribute I assume you're using Angular, in which case you shouldn't really be using jQuery AJAX at all.

Comment: angular is not updating the textarea original value. Data only saved inside as a data property in Angular. I only have experience in Vue, but there I need to emit an event so the input/textarea value gets updated.

Comment: how should a fix the angular to set the value?

Comment: maybe something like `value='ng-model="description"'`?

Comment: Or maybe I should rewrite a jquery function to do the same that angular do.

Comment: Hi guys I posted an answer how I solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the Angular js conflict so I had to write my own jquery function to replace the angular and keep the same angular beraviour on the page, here is my jquery solution for angular replacement:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post_description").keyup(function(){
        // Getting the current value of textarea
        var currentText = $(this).val();
         // Setting the Div content
        $("#text_output").text(currentText);
        //$("#text_output").value(currentText);
         $("#text_output").attr("value", currentText);
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be because you prevent event onclick you have to set event prevent on form submit like this :

```
<form id="post" method="post">
  <div class="input-group">
    <textarea name="post_description" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['description']; ?>" rows="4" ng-model="description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="share_result"></div>
  <a id="share" class="btn-custom">
    <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $lang['share']; ?>
  </a>
  <button type="submit" id="postform">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

When you click on submit button your form will submit and then

```
$("#post").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // here is your code
});
```

Or if you don't want to add this button you have to change from

```
var postimg = $("#post").serialize();
```

to

```
var postimg = {post_description:$("textarea[name='post_description']").val()};
```

Comment: I think it's a angular js conflict with jquery because angular do not update the textarea original value, data is only saved inside as a data property.

Comment: btw why `$("#post").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // here is your code
});` I don't know if that's the case because it should submit even on click, it's submiting on click btw but not sending the value, I am getting `undefined index` on backend, maybe something is wrong with the `.serialize();`function or something else.

Comment: Yes, I think so. May be something wrong with the `.serialize()` function have you try `var postimg = {post_description:$("textarea[name='post_description']").val()};` ?

Comment: I already solved my friend, see my solution on my answer above it was a angular conflict so I had to remove angular js and build the same angular functionality using jquery.

thanks for your answer it was a good alternative too.